# How do I set the weights to a layer only on the first half of the neurons in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I've made a training session that got 70% acc and saved its weights.

I want now to load these weights, from a LSTM this model with (32, 32, 16) outputs for each of the three layers to the same model but with (64, 64, 32) outputs. There are 4 layers and the last one is a softmax with 8 outputs and hasn't changed.

How can I load the "first half" of the weights into this new model?

I'm trying to use the last training session to make the network start from somewhere since the training time got so much higher and my video card isn't that good for training and it is taking loads of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the weights in the same model (not the big model, the small one), or you can simply load them as numpy arrays (I'm not very used to saving and loading in Keras)

If you loaded the weights in the model, find the layers and get the weights as numpy arrays:

```
#for each layer: 
weightsAndBiases = smallModel.layers[i].get_weights() 
   #this is a list with [weights, biases] for the layer i, 
   #may have more elements depending on the type of layer
```

Then, if you want the bigger model to start from some keras initalization (probably better than zeros or ones or a manual initialization), take the weights from the big model after you create it:

```
bigWandB = bigModel.layers[i].get_weights()
    #if not, just create a numpy array with the right shape
```

Now transfer data from `weightsAndBiases` to `bigWandB`.

This example uses the shape you gave, but you should actually check the shape of each array, they don't match the output, and each kind of layer has its own shape. (Please note that some layers may have only one array, some may have two, the classic weights and biases, and the LSTM layers will probably have 3 - check the length of the list):

```
bigWandB[0][:32,:32,:16] = weightsAndBiases[0] #weights for one layer   
bigWandB[1][:32,:32,:16] = weightsAndBiases[1] #biases for the same layer
```

Now set it again to the target layer:

```
bigModel.layers[i].set_weights(bigWandB)
```

Comment: I was thinking about switching my Keras code to Tensorflow. Since I have the weights already I can do something like you've said. It seems doable. I try to do what you said using keras only but if I am not able to, I'll switch my code to Tensorflow and try again. I'll update as soon as possible